# Modified Linux kernel driver to use a virtual address instead of a physical address

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, alsa, dma

I've modified a Linux kernel sound driver to use a new virtual address instead of a physical address when receiving data. When the driver is called on, it reports that the data is 0. I'm looking for any input or feedback on what I may be missing in my process and implementation. If my descriptions below are too vague to give proper feedback, I am happy to expand and provide more details.

I have a physical register at address `0xc0056014`. The hardware register is readable and is correctly initialized in the device tree and Linux kernel(4.4.71). The register holds audio data input from a microphone.

The bits in the physical register are not mapped correctly for playback. This causes audio playback to be filled with white-noise and hissing. I've made a user-space program that will take a raw audio sample and remap the data bits to new raw/wav sample where playback quality is as expected.

My goal is to have this data remapping done in the kernel space.
Example data in physical register: `0x4000f965`
Example data remapped : `0xf9654000`

In the kernel sound driver written for the hardware's audio interface, I've done the following:

1. Initialized a new virtual address with `vzalloc(data_size)`
2. Started a thread.
3. In thread, mapped physical register with `__iomem *regs = ioremap(0xc0056014, 4);`
4. Read the register values into temp buffers & remap the 32bits.
5. Write remap value to virtual address with `memcpy(dst_addr, src_addr, data_size);`
6. Lastly, outside of thread where driver was setting address of physical register, I changed to the virtual address. `dma->peri_addr = dst_addr;`

I'm able to do kernel prints that read the values in my virtual address. The kernel prints show correct values in virtual address, but when calling on the kernel sound driver by use of alsa recording tools, the audio data is being reported as 0.

The kernel reports no errors or warnings and I'm a little stumped at what I'm missing or what to do next. Any pointers, tips, feedback, or questions is welcome! Cheers.

Driver setting address:

```
    if (phy_base == 0xC0056000 && dma == &par->capt)
    {
        void *p;
        size_t data_size;
        data_size = sizeof(unsigned long);  
        p = vzalloc(data_size);
        void *dst_addr = (void *)(p);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Virtual Address is : 0x%p\n", p);

        char our_thread[8]="thread1";
        thread1 = kthread_create(thread_fn,dst_addr,our_thread);

        if((thread1))
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Hit thread1");
            wake_up_process(thread1);
        }           
        dma->peri_addr = dst_addr;
        printk(KERN_INFO "snd i2s1: %s dma peri addr is 0x%p and virtual addr is 0x%p\n", STREAM_STR(i), (void *)dma->peri_addr, p);
    }
```

Thread:

```
    int thread_fn(void *dst_addr) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hit inside thread1\n");

        size_t data_size;
        data_size = sizeof(unsigned long);  

        int k = 0;

        while (1) {

            //printk(KERN_INFO "Virtual Address is : 0x%p\n", p);

            unsigned long read_result;
            void __iomem *regs = ioremap(0xc0056014, 4);    

            read_result = *((unsigned long *) regs);    


            uint32_t sample = read_result;
            uint32_t sample1, sample1buf1, sample1buf2, sample1buf3, sample1buf4;

            sample1buf1 = (sample >> (8*0)) & 0xff; 
            sample1buf2 = (sample >> (8*1)) & 0xff;  
            sample1buf3 = (sample >> (8*2)) & 0xff;         
            sample1buf4 = (sample >> (8*3)) & 0xff;     

            /* Shift bytes from s16le format bit order to s32le format bit order
             [  L   |   R  ]    [          L]
             [  L   |   R  ]    [          R]
                 MSB     MSB              MSB
             [99 f9 | 00 40] -> [00 40 99 f9]
             [cf f9 | 00 40] -> [00 40 cf f9]
             [12 34 | 56 78] -> [56 78 12 34]
            */
            sample1buf1 = sample1buf1 << 16;
            sample1buf2 = sample1buf2 << 24;
            sample1buf4 = sample1buf4 << 8;     

            sample1 = sample1 & 0x00000000;
            sample1 = sample1 | sample1buf3;
            sample1 = sample1 | sample1buf4;
            sample1 = sample1 | sample1buf1;
            sample1 = sample1 | sample1buf2;
            sample = sample1;

            void *src_addr;
            src_addr = &sample;
            memcpy(dst_addr, src_addr, data_size);

            iounmap(regs);  
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**Comment Responses:**

You may be onto what I am missing. Where and when do you expect to use a period completion notification?

peri_addr was the physical data address register. It previously set to 0xc0056014. I changed to point to virtual address.

`dma->peri_addr = phy_base + (i == 0 ? I2S_TXD_OFFSET : I2S_RXD_OFFSET);`

`dma` is pointer to a pcm dma param structure

Once buffer has correctly mapped data, I use `memcpy` to move it to virtual address.

```
    `void *src_addr;
    src_addr = &sample;
    memcpy(dst_addr, src_addr, data_size);`
```

The only handle I do after is point peri_addr to virtual addr.

`dma->peri_addr = dst_addr;`

Comment: What is `peri_addr`? How do you handle the buffer that you report to the ALSA API? And the pointer callback? And period completion notifications?

Comment: See response edit in initial post. You may be onto what I am missing. Where and when do you expect to use a period completion notification?

Comment: What do you mean with "pcm dma param structure"? Where is it used? How? And see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/kernel-api/writing-an-alsa-driver.html.

Comment: What? It is a structure that holds the parameters for the device, in this case a microphone. Where? It is used by the the audio driver to define, set, identify, and reference the audio port's information. How? By the alsa drivers `snd_soc_dai_ops` structure to start, stop, pause, trigger, a device on a sound card.
Inside the struct, there is the following:


 `bool active; `

 `bool (*dma_filter)(struct dma_chan *chan, void *filter_param);`
 `char *dma_ch_name;`
 `dma_addr_t peri_addr;`
 `int bus_width_byte;`
 `int max_burst_byte;`
 `unsigned int real_clock;`
`struct device *dev;`

Comment: `dma_addr_t` is not a physical address on the CPU's memory bus, but on the bus used by the device. In any case, you cannot use a virtual address there. And your driver must have a ring buffer.

Comment: Thanks for info, reading into ring buffers now. So you cannot point `dma_addr_t` to any other kind of address other than the bus used by the device?

Comment: That depends on what your driver does with it; but if it weren't a bus address, it wouldn't be required to be a `dma_addr_t`. In other words, if you're using a virtual address, use a different type, and change *all other code* that uses it.